# Odds of winning a two part drawing

Tags: probability, game-theory, robust-statistics

There is a local drawing that involves being selected out of an estimated 6000 entries, and then correctly selecting 1 of 3 numbers in order to win.  The numbers have are actually cards in a deck that have been selected once per week.  At this point only 3 cards remain and in order to win, you must first be selected and also have picked the "correct" card.  That correct card is already predetermined (queen of hearts).

My question: What are my odds of winning by purchasing 300 entries (estimated 6000 total entries for this contest) and does it make any statistical difference if I play all my chances on 1 number, or spread 100 entries each across all 3 numbers (300/3)?

Lastly, at what number of entries would I be statically be increasing my odd by a significant percentage?

Thanks!

Comment: How many tickets are selected in the first selection?  Is it three and one of them is guaranteed to win the prize?  Or one and if that one doesn't have the right card nobody wins the prize?

Comment: Thank you Ross.  To clarify, one ticket is selected.  If that ticket does not match the winning card, the process is started over again the following week.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to win the first drawing.  It is not fair to assume there are exactly $6000$ tickets sold if you are going to buy very many.  A more reasonable model is that there are $6000$ tickets bought by others.  If you buy $n$ tickets, your chance of winning the first draw is $\frac n{n+6000}$.  For $300$ tickets, you haven't increased the denominator much and your chance here is just under $5\%$. If you bought $6000$ tickets your chance of winning the first draw would not be $100\%$ (which it would be if there were $6000$ sold) but $50\%$  You can plot $\frac n{n+6000}$ to see how the probability increases.

For the second draw, it doesn't matter whether you pick the same card for all your tickets or spread them around.  One particular one of your tickets has won the first draw and you have one chance in three it matches the card.  Of course, if you know the correct card (you said it was predetermined), you should buy all your tickets with that.

Comment: Thank you Ross for your time and consideration of my question!  I appreciate it.